# Which version of Weblogic server supports SHA2 cipher suite

Tags: weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I have Weblogic server 10.3.3 and one of our clients wants to use SHA2 type certificate. We enabled JSSE=true in 10.3.3 and noticed slow performance while talking to this SHA2 using client.
Now we plan to upgrade Weblogic server to support communication with clients using SHA2 type certificates.

1) What lowest(10.3.6 ? )version of Weblogic server should we upgrade to?
2) Where can I find a mapped table of supported cipher suites and Weblogic server versions?

Regards,
DivyaTV

Answer (score 0):

1) 10.3.3 is the lowest version that supports the option to enable SHA2.

2) Since JSSE is the only SSL implementation that is supported, you can use these links to find the supported cipher suites:

JDK 6: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider

JDK 7:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider